# SSH Login permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, admin

On remote computer I configured the following file /etc/ssh/sshd_config. I change Password Authentication to "no". Now I am unable to connect to it. It says permission denied. Is there way to connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, unless you have an account on the server which has a public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` that you have the private key for in on your local machine.

Comment: do you mean something generated with ssh-keygen -t rsa I have it

Comment: Yes. If you have ~/.ssh/id-rsa, and you put the contents of ~/.id-rsa.pub in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote server (and gave it sane/secure permissions), sshing into that server should just work.

Comment: Martijn is correct.  To amplify a bit: If you have previously installed the public half of the keypair in the correct location on the server, and gave it the correct permissions (0600), you should be able to login using the private key.  If you did not do this, and are not able to login that way, then you will require physical access to the console.  If you're lucky, the ISP will have the console connected to an IP terminal server and you may be able to connect that way.  If not, someone is going to have to login at the console and change PasswordAuthentication back to "yes".